# How to give clipboard permission to Android Webivew automatically?

Tags: android, android-webview, clipboard, clipboardmanager

[image: Permission required when URL loaded into browser]

When I load a URL in any browser it asks me for the permission provided in the image.
But when I try to load this URL in Android Webview how can I ask user to provide this permission? OR How can I automatically paste data into Webview fields within my Android app?

There are some restrictions from Android 10 for using the ClipboardManager but the data to be pasted in the webview fields is being copied from the app. This is working for normal fields I want to achieve inside webview.

*I know how to copy/paste data to clipboard using ClipboardManager*